# Kendo Grid filter not working with foreign key column Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My Grid Columns:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo_UI_Bootstrap_Integration.Models.DTO.GridDto>()
                .Name("GridName")
                .Filterable(f => f.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu).Extra(false))
                .EnableCustomBinding(true)
                .Columns(
                columns =>
                {
                    columns.ForeignKey(c => c.HouseId, Model.Homes, "HouseGuid", "HouseName")
                    .EditorTemplateName("HouseDropDown")
                    .Title("House Name")
                    .Filterable(f => f.UI("$.proxy(GridFilter, {field: 'Id'})").Operators(o => o.ForString(e => e.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))));

                    columns.ForeignKey(c => c.NameId, Model.Names, "NameGuid", "Name")
                    .EditorTemplateName("NameDropDown")
                    .Title("Name")
                    .Filterable(f => f.UI("$.proxy(GridFilter, {field: NameId})").Operators(o => o.ForString(e => e.Clear().IsEqualTo("Is equal to").IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))));
```

Grid Filter:

```
function GridFilter(element) {
var grid = "GridName";
var fieldName = this.field;
var gridDataItems = $("#" + grid).data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
var listDataItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < gridDataItems.length; i++) {
    if (gridDataItems[i][fieldName] !== null && $.inArray(gridDataItems[i][fieldName], listDataItems) < 0) {
        listDataItems.push(gridDataItems[i][fieldName]);
    }
}
listDataItems.sort();
$(element).prop("id", fieldName + "DropDown");

element.kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: {
        data: listDataItems
    }
})
```

}

I pass in my ViewModel at the top of the view, the Model consists of a list of Homes and a list of Names from the database.

I want to filter the grid based from the contents of the grid, but the filter function I have specified dosnt get hit and the contents of the model is instead used to populate the filter.

How can I have the filter just look at the contents of the grid instead?

Comment: What is the code for javascript functions `HouseFilter` and `NameFilter` ?  Are their definition scopes global or local to a jQuery document ready closure ? Does the console show any messages?

Comment: The javascript code for both does not get hit, their scopes are local, the console shows no messages. If you still want to see the functions I can append my question?

Comment: Showing the javascript filter functions would make the question more robust.  Try coding the functions outside the ready function.  Why? You will see in page source view that the htmlHelper realizes the grid initialization as a `kendo.syncReady` function -- that may not have access to a function defined within a jQuery ready function closure.

Comment: I have updated my question and made the filter functions into one, as they both did the same thing, this is now called GridFilter, I will try run the function on the FilterInit event of the grid instead of in the Filter.UI section.

Comment: Take a look at the rendered kendo.syncReady (you may have to copy the event code and pretty print it in something like http://jsbeautifier.org/)  Guessing here -- You might have to deeper literalize the $.proxy specification within the htmlHelper (maybe within <text>?).

Comment: In the GridFilter function I set the value of the filter drop down using the element, do you know how I can access this from the FilterInit Event?

Comment: Last one before chat , haha.  The page does not have a lot of grids, so maybe just use regular jQuery select.  `var grid = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid");`

Comment: I have the grid, but I need to be able to get the filter menu dropdown in the jquery, in my current function I use the event passed into automatically and just call kendoDropDown on that list.